# Reverse Array code function error

Tags: python, arrays, list, reverse

Please help me fix this code. This is a function to reverse an integer array so for example: [1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1]. The error is:

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Please give me a solution. Thanks

```
def reverse(array):
   '''
   [1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1]
   This method returns a reversed integer array.
   '''
   size = len(array)
   halfsize = array/2
   size -= 1
   r = array[size]
   temp = None
   for s in range(0, halfsize):
      temp = arrayOne[s]
      array[s] = r
      array[size] = temp
      size -= 1
      r=arrayOne[size]
   return arrayOne


a = reverse ([1, 4, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error is you are getting?

Comment: What's wrong with the builtin `reversed`?

Comment: What is `arrayOne` supposed to be?

Comment: @SethMMorton: He seems to be trying to reverse it in-place rather than to make a reversed copy.

Comment: Told you. Please read the new question :P

Comment: As a side note: You don't need to use two temp variables and three statements to swap two values in Python; just `array[s], array[size] = array[s], array[size]`.

Comment: @abarnert thats right

Comment: can you show me an example solution

Comment: As another side note, you don't need to "declare" variables before using them; that `temp = None` has no effect except to make your program longer, slower, and less readable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to reverse it in-place? If it's for "performance", you might want to compare this to `a[:] = reversed(a)` and see for what sizes, if any, your version is faster; I think you'll be surprised. (If it's just for learning purposes, of course, that's fine.)

Comment: @abarnet or possibly just `list.reverse()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide the length, not the list:

```
halfsize = size // 2
```

This uses the floor division (`//`) operator to ensure the result is an integer.

Your next problem is that you refer to `arrayOne` in several locations, but named your argument just `array`; fix those references and your function works:

```
>>> def reverse(array):
...    '''
...    [1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1]
...    This method returns a reversed integer array.
...    '''
...    size = len(array)
...    halfsize = size // 2
...    size -= 1
...    r = array[size]
...    temp = None
...    for s in range(0, halfsize):
...       temp = array[s]
...       array[s] = r
...       array[size] = temp
...       size -= 1
...       r=array[size]
...    return array
... 
>>> a = reverse ([1, 4, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a
[5, 4, 3, 4, 1]
```

Your function can be simplified somewhat; you do not need a `temp` variable as Python lets you swap values in-place:

```
def reverse(array):
    '''[1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1]

    This method returns a reversed integer array.

    '''
    size = len(array)
    halfsize = size // 2
    size -= 1
    for s in range(halfsize):
        array[s], array[size] = array[size], array[s]
        size -= 1
    return array
```

Also note that you are reversing the list *in place*; there is no real need to return the resulting list object here:

```
>>> a = [4, 6, 42, 1, -5]
>>> reverse(a)
[-5, 1, 42, 6, 4]
>>> a
[-5, 1, 42, 6, 4]
```

Comment: builtins.TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @user2860356: Right, this is Python 3 then?

Comment: @user2860356: Just use `size//2` instead of `size/2`. That will work in both Python 3 and all reasonably recent versions of Python 2.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters Yes, so what do I do??

Comment: @abarnert Now it shows up blank :( Do i have to round the half size or something

Comment: What shows up blank? The code in my answer works, make sure yours matches.

Comment: @user2860356: Note that the function doesn't actually `print` anything, so if you just put it in a script and run it, you won't see anything. You'll need a `print(a)` or similar at the end of the script. (Martijn's example uses the interactive interpreter rather than a script, so he can just type `a` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler  method.

```
def reverseArray(array):
    queue = []
    for element in array:
        queue.insert(0, element)
    return queue
```

For example, if you inputted [2,3,4,5], it would return [5,4,3,2].

It uses the [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#Queues_and_programming_languages) data structure (using insert to enqueue data) in order to reverse it, and then reads the queue's data. Insert is being used to insert data at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a exception because array it's a list. In this line:

```
halfsize = array/2
```

You are dividing a list by an int. You should use

```
halfsize = size/2
```

Instead. But, since i don't know where arrayOne comes from, i can't really say what is the problem.

But, i'll post a alternative solution here, that uses recursion :)

```
def reverse(array, answer=None):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return answer
    if not answer:
        answer = []
    answer.append(array.pop())
    return reverse(array, answer)
```

Recursion is your friend :)
Try to use it.

And, if you aren't doing this for learning purposes, use the reverse built-in function for lists

```
>>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>>> a = a.reverse()
```

And, as a grand finale, a pythonic way to do it:

```
>>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>>> a[::-1]
     [4,3,2,1]
```